# How to restrict admin url from accessing some ip address

Tags: .htaccess, authentication, admin, magento2

I am working on Magento2. As per the requirement, I want to restrict admin URL to some of the IPs and rest should be accessible. Tried multiple solutions from the StackOverflow for Htaccess Method but none of the solution work for me.

Using Apache 2.4 and Magento version 2.3

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(index.php/)?admin [NC]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^11.222.33.444 [OR]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^11.222.55.444 [OR]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^11.333.22.33
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/ [R=302,L]
```

Admin URL should be accessible to certain Ip's.

Comment: The query string is _not_ a part of the URL! This is clearly documented.

Answer (score 0):

**Try below code in your .htaccess file**

```
<Directory>
order deny,allow
deny from  125.xx.10x.11x
</Directory>
```

**Note:** where **125.xx.10x.11x** the IP address which you want to restrict.

**Reference Urls:**

```
   1. https://www.mageplaza.com/kb/restrict-access-magento-2-admin.html         
   2. https://bobcares.com/blog/magento-block-ip-address/
```

**I hope it will help...!!!**